# Should we have numbered tag synonyms for each Star Wars film?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As a suggestion, would it be good to have a corresponding number tag for each *Star Wars* film in the main series (not the anthologies). For example, a synonym for [the-phantom-menace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-phantom-menace) tag might be [star-wars-episode-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-episode-1), or possibly [sw-episode-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-episode-1) (for simplicity.) **Thoughts on my suggestion for adding these synonyms?**

It might also be good to mention that there is already a [star-wars-9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-9) tag for the upcoming 9th film in the sequel trilogy, so unless the [star-wars-9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-9) tag is going to be changed into the name of the film, there is surely some logic in making other corresponding tags for each of the other films in the prequel, original and sequel series. Thoughts?

Comment: [star-wars-9] is there until the name is revealed.

Comment: [star-wars-1], [star-wars-episode-1], [sw-1], [sw-episode-1], [star-wars-the-phantom-menace], [star-wars-tpm], [sw-the-phantom-menace], [sw-tpm], [tpm],  [star-wars-phantom-menace], [star-wars-pm], [sw-phantom-menace], [sw-pm]. How many is too many?

Comment: And in any case a synonym should only be added if it is useful. How useful do you think these tags will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a real need for it, but then again, synonyms cost even less than tags, which are already free.

When the name of the new episode becomes available, it would be useful to synonymise [star-wars-9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-9) to [star-wars-whatever-it-will-be](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-whatever-it-will-be), so that users who don't know the new title yet will be automatically redirected.

On a personal level, my <strike>orderly mind</strike> *mind craving for order* likes it.

---

In conclusion, unless a mod gets bored, I don't see this happening.

Comment: I have downvoted this for one reason, creating tags is free, properly applying them to old questions isn't, it comes at a far greater cost to the site.

Comment: @Edlothiad Creating tag synonyms, though, is absolutely free. Large benefits in terms of better searchability, and no drawbacks whatsoever. I mean, vote however you like of course, but that seems like a poor reason to downvote. Saying tags are free isn't really important to this answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes it is, but tags aren't free, my big worry is people thinking tags are free, adding a tag in one place and it not being clean.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Large benefits if they are useful and used. I can’t see how these would be useful myself.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You don't think any of the millions of people reading Star Wars questions on our site would want to search for questions about "Star Wars Episode I" rather than "The Phantom Menace"?

Comment: @Randal'Thor No because I have 0 evidence of it happening on our site.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yeah, well, there's no way to get "evidence" of what search terms people use, except the 0.001% who post about it on meta like the OP here did. You just have to think about "what *might* someone reasonably search for?" and hope you cover a decent subset of what people actually do search for.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well sure, you could also see people mistagging with [star-wars-1] or something though